# Can jQuery ui Sortable behave like gridster?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to get [jQuery ui Sortable grid](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid) to behave like [gridster](http://gridster.net/)?

Why not use gridster? Because it doesn't work on anything less than IE9.

Looking at the jQuery ui Sortable sample, if you drag number 5 to number 1, number 1 moves to the right.  When I do the same action with gridster, number 1 would move to number 5's position.  It continues to work even with different sized elements.

Is it possible to get jQuery ui Sotables grid to work in a similar manner?

Comment: Check this page http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

Comment: Ran into this post while researching on gridster: Are you able to use gridster with the latest version of jQuery? (1.8.x). . . it seems like it stops working for anything higher than 1.7.2 - can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardly. All jQuery's sortable does is change the order of elements inside the parent element. The "grid behavior" showed in that demo is just the browser's layout engine behaving normally (placing elements from left to right while they fit on parent's `width`, then top to bottom). gridster on the other hand simulates a grid that independs on its elements: even if you remove all tiles from one column, it still occupies space on screen. Elements on columns are ordered, but rows are added/removed as needed.

Replicating that behavior fully would be a lot of work. The closest I could get to [the gridster demo](http://gridster.net/)'s behavior is the [connect lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) example, which you can style like a grid ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/UhTt7/)) but having every element of the same size.

Comment: Thanks.  the example you gave here http://jsfiddle.net/UhTt7/ is basically what I am after but with different sized elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to work with jQuery libraries, there is a jQuery plugin called Isotope which work in a similar way: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html

If you need to add dragging events you can extend the isotope widget following such instructions: http://jstarrdewar.com/blog/2011/10/28/extend-jquery-draggable-to-work-with-isotope