# jQuery UI Sortable Grid with cell spanning vertically

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, grid, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is the link to existing sortable http://jsfiddle.net/bcAH2/5

Just copying the code,

```
 <ul id="sortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default four">4</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
   ...
</ul>
```

​ 
Script

```
$(function() {
   $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
   $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
   $("#sortable .four").css("height","190px");
});
```

​

What I am trying to achieve is to fill spaces below cells 1 2 3 with cells like 5 6 7 8... Is it not possible by drag and drop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this elegant plugin,   [ShapeShift](http://mcpants.github.com/jquery.shapeshift/) which does the job nicely

There is another forked version of gridster, thought worth sharing here, [gridster.js Forked](https://github.com/dustmoo/gridster.js)

Answer (score 6):

There's a jQuery plugin called [gridster](http://gridster.net/) that might do what you want (see the demo in the front page). A simpler but less flexible alternative, as explained in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13191031/520779), is to create several columns and make each one sortable, connecting them to allow dragging from one to another. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/UhTt7/1/) close to yours, but not with some caveats:

- You can have tiles with greater `height`, but not with greater `width`, without messing the layout (gridster does not have this limitation);
- You can't have "empty spaces" between two tiles in one column (gridster has less limitations on that);
- If you remove all tiles from one column, it will disappear (unless you style it to have a fixed width, with or without contents; gridster does not have this limitation).

Comment: Tried girdster, not worthy for my problem. But your other solution is close enough.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not in drag and drop, but the flow of the floated elements.

All the elements after "four" will align to it, and since it's higher - it takes more space. So the space in the second row in front of "four" is actually not the part of the "grid".

Actually, there is no grid here, since you're working with floated elements.

Hope this helps you to understand why it can't be achieved with the current styling and scripting.

Comment: Agreed its just when column spans more space and not when elements in a row spans. My question is there a way to achieve it?!